# What is the difference between these two classes?

Tags: python

```
class SortedDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        if data is None:
            data = {}
        super(SortedDict, self).__init__(data)
```

and

```
class SortedDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, data={}):
        dict(data)
```

I think they are same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dict(data)` just creates a dictionary from `data` without saving the result anywhere. `super(SortedDict, self).__init__(data)` on the other hand calls the parent class constructor.

Also, in the case of multiple inheritance, using `super` ensures that all the right constructors are called in the right order. Using `None` as a default argument instead of a mutable `{}` ensures that those other constructors [don't accidentally modify `SortedDict`s default argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument).

Answer (score 1):

The first class doesn't seem to work

```
class SortedDict2(dict):
    def __init__(self, data={}):
        dict(data)

class SortedDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        if data is None:
            data = {}
        super(SortedDict, self).__init__(data)



x = SortedDict2("bleh")
y = SortedDict({1: 'blah'})

print x
print y

File "rere.py", line 3, in __init__
 dict(data)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required


x = SortedDict2({1: "bleh"})
y = SortedDict({1: 'blah'})

print x
print y

>> {}
>>{1: 'blah'}
```